# Hide other databases for particular user in azure sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

Currently I am facing issue with Azure SQL Server. I have to give permission to login for QA person on Azure Database for testing purpose. I have other databases also, and not want to seen by QA person for security purpose.

In General SQL Server, **Deny View Any Database** can work for me but in Azure SQL Server I am not able to create same. It gives me error 'Securable class 'server' not supported in this version of SQL Server.'

How to hide databases to particular user only in azure SQL Database.

Comment: create a login in the relevant Database.....

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this document https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-logins/ but I've been dealing with the same puzzle myself and unless you can use Active Directory there seems to be no way to accomplish the same level of LOGIN access granularity as with standalone SQL Server instances.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create database level firewall rule using SQL server management studio as follows.

1. Connect to your azure SQL server using SQL server management studio.
2. Click new query by write clicking your database in object explorer.
3. Copy this query and execute after modifying IP address to your public IP address.

   ```
   EXECUTE sp_set_database_firewall_rule N'Example DB Rule','0.0.0.4','0.0.0.4';
   ```

> **NOTE** - Please make sure that database-level firewall rules can only be configured by using Transact-SQL statements and only after you have configured the first [server-level firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-security-tutorial) rule.